# Saving a date in NSUserDefaults (as NSString) not working

Tags: objective-c, datetime, ios4, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save this date in NSUSerDefaults:

```
2011-04-14T13:18:25+0000
```

But I don't want the last bit (+0000), so I chopped it off using this method:

```
NSString *since = [last objectForKey:@"updated_time"];
NSString *cutOff = @"+0000"; 
NSRange range = [since rangeOfString:cutOff];
self.lastUpdated = [since substringToIndex:range.location];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastUpdated forKey:@"lastUpdated"];
```

As you can see, it's just a very simple operation that will chop the above string to this:

```
2011-04-14T13:18:25
```

However when I load this from NSUserDefaults, I get this:

```
2011-04-14 13:18:25 +0000
```

Can anyone tell me why?

UPDATE:

I declared lastUpdated as usual in .h:

```
@interface TwitModel
{
    NSString *lastUpdated;
}

@property (retain) NSString *lastUpdated;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize lastUpdated;
```

When I want to load it:

```
    if(self.lastUpdated == nil) {
        self.lastUpdated = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastUpdated"];
    }
```

Comment: How ist lastUpdated declared? Show us the code please.

Comment: Although this shouldn't matter but you are not being consistent. You are setting self.lastUpdate then you are passing just lastUpdated to the `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Hmm I changed it to self.lastUpdate, but as you said, it shouldn't matter. I don't see any difference

Comment: What is `last` in the line: `NSString *since = [last objectForKey:@"updated_time"];`?

Comment: it's just an nsdictionary that has the last updated time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `synchronize` on `NSUserDefaults` in order for it to properly save the data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's my working code:

```
// Output previous launch's stored value
NSLog(@"Value From Previous Launch: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastUpdated"]);

NSString *since = @"2011-04-14T13:18:25+0000";
NSLog(@"Since: %@", since);
NSString *cutOff = @"+0000"; 
NSRange range = [since rangeOfString:cutOff];
NSString* lastUpdated = [since substringToIndex:range.location];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastUpdated forKey:@"lastUpdated"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastUpdated"]);
```

And the output:

```
2011-04-14 08:52:29.972 TestApp[2117:207] Value From Previous Launch: 2011-04-14T13:18:25
2011-04-14 08:52:29.973 TestApp[2117:207] Since: 2011-04-14T13:18:25+0000
2011-04-14 08:52:29.975 TestApp[2117:207] Value: 2011-04-14T13:18:25
```

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't seem to work either... Doesn't it say somewhere in the Apple docs that this call is not actually needed?

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, `Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.` However, when trying to debug issues like this, I tend to be as explicit as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Unfortunately it still gives me incorrect result... I wonder if this is because some string characters are not meant to be saved in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Any character that can be saved in a string can be saved in `NSUserDefaults`. An alternative to this would be to do something like Caleb suggested, and store the actual date itself in `NSUserDefaults` instead of a string representation. May provide more and better options down the road should you need to work with the date.

Comment: OK... This may sound really weird, but what's happening is that I'm using an open source framework in my app, and that framework uses lastUpdated key in NSUserDefaults for something else! That's why every time I write to lastUpdated, it gets rewritten to another value! Damn I hate late night coding =) Thanks very much for your answer though! You're the one who convinced me that my original code is right and there must be some other force that's driving this bug!

Comment: And I'd also consider saving the actual date too. I might need it. Thank you very much! You are a great help to me tonight!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say -- can you show us the code that reloads the value? It might be simpler, conceptually at least, if you use a date formatter to produce a string in the format you want. Or, just save the date itself, and worry about formatting it when you need to display it.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but as you can see from the above, chopping off the last bits (+0000) takes three lines of code. I don't want to do that every time I load...